# Do I need commas around "мол"?

Tags: пунктуация

Do I need commas around мол?

For example,

> Он говорил, что мол математики занимаются ерундой.

Comment: it is a stylistic flaw (albeit marginally acceptable) to use both *что* and *мол* in this sentence.

Comment: @Quassnoi , or is it possibly a pretend colloquial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, usually it is [separated by commas](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_421&layout=item) (by the way the term you need to know to make googling easier is "обособление [запятыми]"):

> **мол**, частица -Указывает на то, что говорящий передает чужие слова, чужое мнение или приводит свои слова, сказанные в другое время.
>   Обособляется, сближаясь по значению с вводными словами, указывающими
>   на источник сообщения.

There's another word used in the same context `дескать` and it is also separated by commas.

Comment: @brilliant Easy to guess, by the way: «*мол*» has nothing to do with «*занимаются*», not being connected to it through describing the same action (relationship of things), therefore it should be separated (the basic principle that works nearly always, without looking up any rule-books).

Comment: there's also  the particle "де"

Comment: @VCH250 good point. My understanding though is that it's reduced form of  `дескать`

Comment: @shabunc: it's the other way around, *дескать* is from *де*

Comment: you mean дескать isn't a verb (wasn't) ?